# Не работающие C типы int32_t, int_fast32_t и int_least32_t в Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-c++

Какие аналоги могут быть типам `int32_t`, `int_fast32_t`, и `int_least32_t` в Visual Studio? Компилятор не знает таких типов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#include <stdint.h>` попробуйте, эти типы там описаны, вроде.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

Если вы используете старую версию Visual Studio (старее чем 2012), можете воспользоваться [msinttypes](https://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/)